# Dependency error updating PHPMyAdmin

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, yum, phpmyadmin

I apologize for my Linux knowledge which is really basic. I'm troubleshooting since a few hours trying different approaches but I'm still failing.

When I try the following instruction:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test  install phpMyAdmin --skip-broken
```

I get this error message. And if I do update PHPMyAdmin just by decompressing the files it simply doesn't work. Can you explain me what this error is saying to me? Maybe I need that dependencies to be updated?

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.denit.net
 * city-fan.org: nervion.us.es
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: mirror.denit.net
 * remi: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * remi-test: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
 * rpmforge: ftp.nluug.nl
 * updates: mirror.nforce.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.7.1-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(tecnickcom/tcpdf) < 7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpseclib/phpseclib) < 3 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpmyadmin/sql-parser) < 5 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpmyadmin/shapefile) < 3 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpmyadmin/motranslator) < 4 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(google/recaptcha) < 2 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(tecnickcom/tcpdf) >= 6.2 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpseclib/phpseclib) >= 2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpmyadmin/sql-parser) >= 4.1.2 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpmyadmin/shapefile) >= 2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(phpmyadmin/motranslator) >= 3.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(google/recaptcha) >= 1.1 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php(language) >= 5.5 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-xmlwriter for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-xml for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-recode for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mysqli for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-gd for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(fedora/autoloader) for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-gmp for package: php-phpseclib-2.0.6-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-json for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-json for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-json for package: php-google-recaptcha-1.1.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-zip for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8 for package: php-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8 for package: php-cli-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-fedora-autoloader.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gd-last(x86-64) >= 2.1.1 for package: php-gd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.3()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-google-recaptcha.noarch 0:1.1.3-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-mysqlnd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-phpmyadmin-motranslator.noarch 0:3.3-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(symfony/expression-language) < 4 for package: php-phpmyadmin-motranslator-3.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(symfony/expression-language) >= 2.8 for package: php-phpmyadmin-motranslator-3.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-phpmyadmin-shapefile.noarch 0:2.1-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser.noarch 0:4.1.7-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-phpseclib.noarch 0:2.0.6-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-phpseclib-2.0.6-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-recode.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librecode.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-recode-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.13-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.2.13-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts for package: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:2.33-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-1.el6 for package: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-1.el6.noarch
---> Package gd-last.x86_64 0:2.2.4-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: gd-last-2.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.10-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-48.el6_8 for package: php-devel-5.3.3-48.el6_8.x86_64
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-gmp.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.5-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-symfony3-expression-language.noarch 0:3.2.9-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(symfony/cache) = 3.2.9 for package: php-symfony3-expression-language-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch
---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtidy-0.99.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-tidy-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package recode.x86_64 0:3.6-28.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-6.el6_2.1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dejavu-fonts-common.noarch 0:2.33-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: fontpackages-filesystem for package: dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-1.el6.noarch
---> Package libtidy.x86_64 0:0.99.0-34.20091203.0.el6 will be installed
---> Package libwebp.x86_64 0:0.4.3-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libzip5.x86_64 0:1.2.0-1.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be updated
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php-pecl-jsonc-devel(x86-64) for package: php-devel-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
---> Package php-symfony3-cache.noarch 0:3.2.9-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-symfony3-common = 3.2.9-1.el6.remi for package: php-symfony3-cache-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(psr/log) < 2.0 for package: php-symfony3-cache-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(psr/cache) < 2.0 for package: php-symfony3-cache-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(psr/log) >= 1.0 for package: php-symfony3-cache-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-composer(psr/cache) >= 1.0 for package: php-symfony3-cache-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fontpackages-filesystem.noarch 0:1.41-1.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-PsrLog.noarch 0:1.0.2-2.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64 0:1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20100412-x86-64 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64
---> Package php-psr-cache.noarch 0:1.0.1-3.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package php-symfony3-common.noarch 0:3.2.9-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.5-4.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be updated
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-process-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-gmp-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-mbstring-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-gd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-xml-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-recode-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-pdo-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-tidy-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-cli-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-bcmath-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(language) >= 5.4 for package: php-phpmyadmin-shapefile-2.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php(language) >= 5.5.9 for package: php-symfony3-common-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php(language) >= 5.5 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php(language) >= 5.5 for package: php-google-recaptcha-1.1.3-1.el6.remi.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.5-4.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.30-2.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-process-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-gmp-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-mbstring-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-gd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-xml-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-recode-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-pdo-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-tidy-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-cli-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.30-2.el6.remi for package: php-bcmath-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.5-4.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.3-48.el6_8 will be updated

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    dejavu-fonts-common-2.33-1.el6.noarch from base
    dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-1.el6.noarch from base
    fontpackages-filesystem-1.41-1.1.el6.noarch from base
    gd-last-2.2.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi
    libXpm-3.5.10-2.el6.x86_64 from base
    libtidy-0.99.0-34.20091203.0.el6.x86_64 from city-fan.org
    libwebp-0.4.3-3.el6.x86_64 from epel
    libzip5-1.2.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi
    php-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-PsrLog-1.0.2-2.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-bcmath-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-cli-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-common-5.6.30-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-common-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-devel-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-fedora-autoloader-1.0.0-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-gd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-gmp-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-google-recaptcha-1.1.3-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-mbstring-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-mysqlnd-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-pdo-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-pecl-jsonc-devel-1.3.10-2.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-2.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 from remi
    php-pecl-zip-1.14.0-0.2.20170301dev.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-phpmyadmin-motranslator-3.3-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-phpmyadmin-shapefile-2.1-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser-4.1.7-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-phpseclib-2.0.6-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-process-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-psr-cache-1.0.1-3.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-recode-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-symfony3-cache-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-symfony3-common-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-symfony3-expression-language-3.2.9-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.13-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    php-tidy-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    php-xml-5.6.30-2.el6.remi.x86_64 from remi-test
    phpMyAdmin-4.7.1-1.el6.remi.noarch from remi
    recode-3.6-28.1.el6.x86_64 from base
    t1lib-5.1.2-6.el6_2.1.x86_64 from base
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ you obviously don't need "remi-test"

2/ you need at least PHP 5.6 to get the latest phpMyAdmin version (as [explained](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/08/06/PHP-version-5.6-needed))

So try:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56  install phpMyAdmin
```

If you don't want to upgrade PHP, and keep default version 5.3.3 from base repository, you have to keep old phpMyAdmin version available in EPEL.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask a very very short explanation of what is Remi and Epel?

Comment: EPEL, see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL and Remi, see https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-site-introduction